# How to use an R String variable with SQL

Tags: sql, r, dbi, dbplyr

I have an R string which is such:

```
food_type<-"'noodles','pasta','burger','pizza','cake'"
```

I need to pass this string into SQL

```
res<-paste(Select * From abc1 where food in '",food_type,"'and price>=100;")
```

this result in NULL (although it shouldn't be so)

I used

```
translate_sql('noodles','pasta','burger','pizza','cake')
```

which returns

```
<SQL>noodles
<SQL>pasta
<SQL>burger
<SQL>pizza
<SQL>cake
```

and when I used

```
translate_sql("'noodles','pasta','burger','pizza','cake'")
```

it returns ('''noodles'',''pasta'',''burger'',''pizza'',''cake''')

I just want to put this in SQL query. TIA

Comment: (1) I don't know the sql dialect you are using. But shouldn't it be `res <- paste("Select * From abc1 where food in (",food_type,") and price>=100;")`? (2) What are you trying to do with `translate_sql`? As far as I know, `dbplyr::translate_sql` converts `R` syntax into SQL syntax.

Comment: **Don't do that**. Read about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [how to do that safely in R](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/).

Comment: __You can do it.__ @Jean-ClaudeArbaut The OP is probably not running a public Pizza, Pasta etc. service. SQL string sanitization is probably not the priority here.

Comment: @andschar Sure, *what could go wrong*? 1/ I don't know what the OP is running, or what he will be running in the future, or where his code will eventually end up, and what people using it will assume about it being well written. 2/ I don't know either what the reader passing by will be running. 3/ It's a well know security flaw and it has a correct and elegant solution. No excuses. So I insist: don't do that, ever. Even if it looks safe in the OP's context (which is irrelevant here), it's anyway a very bad habit.

Comment: @andschar By the way, these days R code often ends up on a Shiny *server*. Then anything can happen, and no need to operate a web shop to have sensitive data that you don't want to leak. And R coders have usually very little knowledge about security and risks in their code. Definitely not a good idea to fill Stack Overflow with that kind of answer. It's bad period.

Comment: Imho, you need to worry about SQL injections when you go public. If you run your local database server and query it with scripts from your machine, I wouldn't worry about SQL-injections. Though, I agree with you that it should be taught early.

Comment: @andschar, sql injection does not need to be malicious, it can be accidental as well. Just because the OP is not (at this point) running on a public-facing server does not mean it is a good practice to encourage. We aren't trying to teach tricks to make the OP a professional in SQL development: these recommendations are also based on Analysts who have been burned by simple (non-malicious) sql-injection mistakes.

Comment: @andschar ... while technically SQL Injection is all about malicious intent, the intent of my previous comment is that SQL "spoiling" does not need to be malicious to break things.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that one "*never*" uses `paste` or `sprintf` to add data into a query; I put quotes around "never" because there may be exceptions, such as `"... where somevalue > 3"`, and perhaps some other corner-cases that are "always safe". Even then, `paste("... where somevalue > ", myvalue)` works fine until it is accidental `NA`, in which case the DBMS will error.

There are generally (at least) two reasons why:

- DBMSes tend to want to analyze queries, optimize them, and cache this optimized version of the query. This way, the next time you send this exact query, the time spent analyzing and optimizing the query will be avoided, and the second and subsequent calls should be an iota faster. Granted, for the vast majority of users' queries, this time is negligible, but longer queries (and/or much larger data) will benefit from this caching.

  *However*, changing one thing in the query often leads to a cache-miss, meaning `"... where somevalue in ('a','b')"` and `"... where somevalue in ('a','c')"` are different-enough, even if the rest of the query is identical. (Bound-parameters, below, resolves this.)
- Even inadvertent data-poisoning can have a similar effect to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
  (technically, accidental injection that just breaks the query is not "SQL injection", but I'll gloss over that technicality for now). `paste` and `sprintf` do not safeguard against incorrect quoting/escaping.

Mitigations:

1. (Preferred) Use `DBI` parameter binding. For `"somevalue in (...)"` set membership, it takes an extra step to get it right, but this is not difficult. A great guide is https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/, though the [`?dbBind`](https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbbind) is a good start as well. Long-story-short:

   ```r
   food_type <- c("noodles", "pasta", "burger", "pizza", "cake")
   qmarks <- paste(rep("?", length(food_type)), collapse = ",")
   qmarks
   # [1] "?,?,?,?,?"
   qry <- sprintf("Select * From abc1 where food in (%s) and price >= ?", qmarks)
   qry
   # [1] "Select * From abc1 where food in (?,?,?,?,?) and price >= ?"
   result <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, qry, params = c(as.list(foodlist), 100))
   ```
2. Use `glue::glue_sql` to safely handle quoting/escaping of strings. While this step still negates the benefits of DBMS caching, it's still safer.

   ```r
   food_type <- c("noodles", "pasta", "burger", "pizza", "cake")
   price_limit <- 100
   glue::glue_sql("Select * From abc1 where food in ({food_type*}) and price >= {price_limit}", .con = con)
   # <SQL> Select * From abc1 where food in ('noodles', 'pasta', 'burger', 'pizza', 'cake') and price >= 100
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is not even valid R expression, you are missing one quote:

```
res<-paste(Select * From abc1 where food in '",food_type,"'and price>=100;")
```

Should be

```
res<-paste("Select * From abc1 where food in '",food_type,"'and price>=100;")
```

But that is still not good sql since you have extra quote in res:

```
    "Select * From abc1 where food in ' 'noodles','pasta','burger','pizza','cake' 'and price>=100;"
```

Valid sql is `select * from x where y in ('a', 'b', 'c')`

So you do this:

```
> res<-paste("select * from abc1 where food in (",food_type,") and price>=100;")
> res
[1] "select * from abc1 where food in ( 'noodles','pasta','burger','pizza','cake' ) and price>=100;"
```

Answer (score -1):

I assumed your R string to actually be a vector. If so, you can run the code below. Otherwise just paste it like in @tomas-greif's answer.

```r
food_type = c('noodles','pasta','burger','pizza','cake')

res = paste0 (
  "SELECT *
   FFROM abc1
   WHERE food IN ('", paste0(food_type, collapse = "', '") , "') AND price >= 100;")
```